# How to get an ArcGIS custom tool to run fom the command line?

Tags: arcpy, arcobjects, error-000582

I have been experimenting with ESRI's CalculateArea custom tool and it works fine running  within ArcGIS from a toolbox.  Then I wanted to see if I could run it as a standalone script from the commandline like this:

```
c:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe calcAreaTest.py
```

calcAreaTest.py

```
import arcpy
arcpy.AddToolbox(r"D:\Toolbox.tbx")
arcpy.CalculateArea(r"D:\data.gdb\data", "Area")
```

The following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\calcAreaTest.py", line 3, in <module>
    arcpy.CalculateArea(r"D:\data.gdb\data", "Area")
  File "D:\Toolbox.tbx", line 25, in CalculateArea
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution.
```

I can paste the same code from calcAreaTest.py into the ArcGIS Python code window and it works.  Anybody know how I can get it to work from the commandline?

Here is the link to the source code of the GPCalculateArea tool if anybody is interested at looking it.
[GPCalculateArea custom tool](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/ViewCodePages/914fc3ff-817b-4825-8f15-4df2d725c370GPCalculateAreaCalculateAreaFunction.cs.htm)

Comment: What happens if you try arcpy.CalculateAreas_stats(r"D:\data.gdb\data", "Area")?

Comment: Register your tool DLL with the GAC. Getting .Net to play nice from Python.exe is a bit of a precise and annoying task.

Comment: Registering the dll to the GAC still produces the same error.

Comment: Trying to alias the toolbox to "stats" has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

In arcpy you need to use ImportToolbox:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"D:\Toolbox.tbx", "mytbx")
arcpy.CalculateArea_mytbx(r"D:\data.gdb\data", "Area")
```

or

```
arcpy.mytbx.CalculateArea(r"D:\data.gdb\data", "Area")
```